# How to calculate the limit of f(f(x)) if f(x) is a piecewise function?

Tags: calculus, limits, function-and-relation-composition

Say f(x) is some piece wise function, and on some interval it is a quadratic equation. How do we determine $$\lim_{x \to -2} f(f(x))$$
Would it just be first we sub the quadratic inside the quadratic and then determine the solution? Or is there something more? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is $f(f(-2))$ unless $f$ has discontinuity around $x=-2$ or around $x=f(-2)$, in which case it is undefined.

Comment: So in my case, $x=f(-2)$ is a hole in the graph, so that means even if $f(f(-2))$ has a result, this limit does not exist?

Comment: Are there $\lim_{x\rightarrow-2-0}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow-2+0}f(x)$ (left and right limits in $-2$)? Are they equal? How do they relate to $f(-2)$? I am not sure what "hole in the graph" means :)

Comment: The limit might exist even if there is a discontinuity at $-2$... If $\lim_{x\to -2^+} f(x) = a$ and $\lim_{x\to -2^-} f(x) = b$ and $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $b$, and happen to have the same function value (i.e. $f(a)=f(b)$), then the limit exists. There are more contrived examples as well, with discontinuities at $a$ and $b$, using that $f$ is either increasing or decreasing before and after $-2$.

Comment: @Arthur so both of those statements are true, what is the limit of $f(f(x))$ then? Because the point at f(f(x)) is a point-discontinuity, do I approach f(f(x)) from the left or right?

Comment: That depends on whether $f$ approaches its value at $-2$ from below or from above.